# Running two loops at the same time on my discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, python-asyncio

So my discord bot in python has the task to send an embed as soon as the user sends the message "$start". After this the code is starting a while loop and checking if a user has reacted. Simultaneously I want to edit the message of the bot every second so I can display some kind of timer to show the users how much time they have left to react but I dont know how to implement a timer running at the same time. Would it be useful to use `multiprocessing` for this one?
Here is my very specific code if anyone needs it to answer my question :)

```
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    timer = 120
    remTime = timer
    seedCapital = 10000
    sessionEmpty = True

players[ctx.author] = seedCapital

em = discord.Embed(title = "New Poker Session", description = "Waiting for players to join ...\nreact with  to join or ▶️ to start (only host)", color = discord.Color.green())
#em.add_field(name = "2 minutes remaining from now on!", value = "")
botMsg = await ctx.send(embed = em)
await botMsg.add_reaction("")
await botMsg.add_reaction("▶️")

while True:
    mom0 = time.perf_counter()
    try:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout = remTime, check = lambda reaction, user: reaction.emoji in ["", "▶️"])
        #msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout = remTime, check = lambda m: m.channel == ctx.channel)
        #print(f"receiving message: {msg.content}")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        break

    if reaction.emoji == "":
        sessionEmpty = False
        await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} joined the session!")
        players[user] = seedCapital
    elif user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji == "▶️":
        break

    mom1 = time.perf_counter()
    neededTime = mom1 - mom0
    remTime -= neededTime
    print(remTime)

if not sessionEmpty:
    await ctx.send("starting session ...")
    #start session
else:
    await ctx.send("Noone joined your session :(")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `asyncio.gather` to run coroutines concurrently.

```py
#after command
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=30) #30 seconds to react

async def coro():
   for i in range(30, 0, 5):
       await botMsg.edit(f'time remaining: {i}') #send another message if you don't want old content to be erased
       await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def coro2():
   while datetime.now() <= endtime:
      #do stuff

await asyncio.gather(coro(), coro2())
```

Note: There might be a small delay between the completion of the two coroutines.

References:

- [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently)

Edit: Here is the small delay I mentioned [image: Open In Colab]

Comment: So my problem would be that I am trying to access the same message in both of the coroutines. I am trying to 1. wait for reactions on the message, 2. update the message every second. But if I'd use asyncio.gather I'd had to make two seperate functions.

Comment: yeah that is not a problem, If you define the function inside the same scope they will have access to all the variables, the problem is running them concurrently, which is what asyncio.gather does

Comment: @Toilettenbrain, did it work? Are you still stuck?